# Unable to install selenium standalone server using webdriver-manager

Tags: node.js, protractor, webdriver-manager, selenium-server

I am new to Protractor. When I try to install selenium standalone server I am getting

```
webdriver-manager update
[16:08:09] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 140.82.112.5:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Request instance at:
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '140.82.112.5',
  port: 443
}
```

My Java and Protractor versions

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
protractor --version
7.0.0
```

I tried to run

```
webdriver-manager update standalone --ignore _ssl --proxy http://XXXXXX.XXXXX.XXXX:XXXX --gecko=false
[16:12:56] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\standalone-response.xml 'http://XXXXXX.XXXXX.XXXX:XXXX/' -H 'host:selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com'
[16:12:56] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml 'http://XXXXXX.XXXXX.XXXX:XXXX/' -H 'host:chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
[16:12:57] I/downloader - curl -oC:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar 'http://XXXXXX.XXXXX.XXXX:XXXX/3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar' -H 'host:selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com'
internal/streams/legacy.js:61
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar'
}
```

webdriver-manager status is

```
webdriver-manager status
[16:14:09] I/status - chromedriver version available: 84.0.4147.30 [last]
[16:14:09] I/status - selenium standalone is not present
[16:14:09] I/status - geckodriver is not present
[16:14:09] I/status - IEDriverServer is not present
[16:14:09] I/status - android-sdk is not present
[16:14:09] I/status - appium is not present
```

Can someone help me on installing the selenium standalone server.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to install standalone selenium server.